# causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type. The main error on the place "{" on `builder: (context, state) {` the code is below

```
home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationUnintialized) {
            return SplashPage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
            return MapSample();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage(userRepository: userRepository);
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Remove the last `if` of the `LoadingIndicator`, just return the loading widget if all the above fails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationUnintialized) {
            return SplashPage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
            return MapSample();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage(userRepository: userRepository);
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
            return LoadingIndicator();
        },
      ),
```

if you find this is useful please accept the answer